# AWS Node App Gets 503 "Back-end server is at capacity"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I've got three setups:

1) local server running Node app

2) remote server running Node app

3) remote server running Nginx

The two remote setups are on the same machine, which is an AWS instance.  My basic problem is that #2 gives me a 503 "Back-end server is at capacity", while #1 and #3 both work fine.

If it wasn't for #3 I'd think that my AWS configuration was the problem, and if it wasn't for #1 I'd think my Node app was broken.  But since I know the app works, and I know the AWS config works, I have no idea what could be causing the 503.

If anyone with more AWS experience could point me towards any possible source of the 503 (or even just towards related AWS documentation) I would greatly appreciate it.

**Other Details**

I already checked my `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log`, but it's basically empty.  I also checked the Nginx logs (per Paulpro's suggestion), but since Nginx runs fine there's nothing helpful there.

Also, the reason I'm pretty that my back-end server is not actually at capacity is that the Node app is tiny (just a "hello world").

Also, this instance was created using EBS (Elastic Beanstalk); I'm not sure that's relevant but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Check you nginx logs.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not clear on how they would be relevant.  Nginx runs fine on its own, and when the app is running Nginx isn't, so I wouldn't expect to see anything in the nginx logs (and indeed I checked them and nothing is out of the ordinary).

Comment: I'm assuming you are using an ELB? They give a "Back-end server is at capacity" error when a health check is failing. Check your ELB health check rules and make sure that they are working.

Comment: I am, so that sounds very promising!  Could I possibly trouble you to put ever so slightly more detailed instructions on how I can check the rules (and that they're working) in an answer, and then if that turns out to be the problem I can accept that answer?

Comment: To follow up, I found the load balancer for my instance in AWS, checked it's health check, and corrected some things (it was using tcp/port 80/`/index.htm`, and I corrected it to https/port 443/`/`) ... but it's still not working.  I imagine I should try performing the health check myself manually somehow, but since I can't access the machine (presumably because of the failing health check) I don't understand how I can get to it's health check point to see what's wrong.

Comment: The machine should have a public ip that you can access directly to test the health check (you will need to whitelist your own IP to have access to port 443 in a security group of that instance).

Comment: I didn't have an inbound rule on the security group, so thanks, that helped.  I'm now to a point where the app works if I `wget http://appUrl:443`, but not if I `wget https://appUrl:443`.  Since someone else setup the HTTPS part I'm going to ask them for help, but the important thing is that I appear to have solved by 503 problem!  If you provide an answer which summarizes your comments I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Are you sure the SSL termination isn't happening on the ELB? It probably made sense to only connect to the server on port 80, and allow the ELB to serve the SSL certificate.